# How to navigate to another view on a Webview Event in React Native?

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using **react-native-webview-messaging** to get event from a web view.

When the event is triggered i manage to change the state but I can not navigate to a new View.

This is what I do :

```
componentDidMount() {

    const { messagesChannel } = this.webview;

    messagesChannel.on('json', json => this.setState({
        message: json,

    }, () => {

        return (
            <GoToThisView />
        );

    }));

  }
```

So my state changes to the JSON that I get from the webview but the return statement doesn't open a new page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using StackNavigator in your app then you can directly use navigate('screen_name') to navigate to the screen you want. Return is used with render.

```
componentDidMount() {

    const { messagesChannel } = this.webview;

    messagesChannel.on('json', json => this.setState({
        message: json,

    }, () => {

            navigate('GoToThisView');                  

    }));
}
```

The screen name 'GoToThisView' must have been defined .